# What is the best way to determine terminal height dynamically in C on Unix/Linux?

Tags: c, linux, unix, terminal, height

I want to display a header every X lines where X makes the header show up as the last one scrolls off the screen.  The user may change the terminal size and the program should know the answer.  Something roughly like

```
i = get_lines()+1;
while (1) {
    if (i > get_lines()) {
        printf("header");
        i = 0;
    } else {
        i++;
    }
    do_stuff();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the current terminal height with TIOCGWINSZ:

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h> /* needed for lines */
#include <signal.h>    /* needed for lines */
#include <stdio.h>     /* needed for printf */
#include <time.h>      /* needed for sleep */

unsigned short lines;
static void get_lines(int signo) {
    struct winsize ws;
    ioctl(fileno(stdout), TIOCGWINSZ, &ws);
    lines = ws.ws_row;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int i;
    struct timespec ts;

    get_lines(SIGWINCH);
    signal(SIGWINCH, get_lines);

    i = lines;
    while (1) {
        if (i >= lines) {
            printf("header\n");
            i = 3; /* 3 not 1 because header + last empty line */
        } else {
            i++;
        }
        printf("line\n");
        ts.tv_sec = 0;
        ts.tv_nsec = 500000000;
        nanosleep(&ts, NULL);
    }
}
```

The number of lines is now in `ws.ws_row`.

When the user changes the terminal size (i.e. resizes his terminal window), a `SIGWINCH` is sent to the foreground process. So you should establish a *signal handler* for this event and re-read the window size.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds exactly like what I need.